# Responsive Hover Code

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm creating a map/floorplan with hover but the hover image + text does not seem to be responsive to the image. I'm using fixed value and I understand I should use % but even when I do, I'm not experienced enough to get it to work.

[How it looks when image is not made responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgyA9.jpg)

[How it looks when image is made responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlqAb.jpg)

CSS:

```
.hoverinfosupermarket {
    position: absolute;
    top:79%;
    left: 37%;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6e706f;
    cursor: default;
}

.hoverinfosupermarket p {
    display: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size:10px;
}

.hoverinfosupermarket:hover p {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverinfosupermarket">
    <span>#B1-01</span>
    <p>
        <img alt="Supermarket" src="/cs/w/img/supermarket.jpg" /><br />
        Supermarket
    </p>
</div>
```

The map/floorplan is actually inside a tab and the hover image + text is within this tab as well.

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMap(event, 'B1')">B1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMap(event, 'L1')">L1</button>           
</div>

<script>

function openMap(evt, mapName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(mapName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

CSS :

```
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want the image to scale with the floor plan? If so, how does the floor plan scale?

Comment: Yes, for the hover image + text to scale with the floor plan. The floor plan is responsive and scales according to the CMS which is max-width 100% and height and width auto.

Comment: You could use the CSS `calc()` function and do something like thie `calc(scale*vw)`, where `scale = relation between the images`.

Answer (score 0):

You container `<div class="hoverinfosupermarket">` should have `position: relative` and then add `position: absolute` to `p` tag. After specifying these, use pixels to specify the top and left. It would work like charm.

Comment: Thanks for the kind assistance, I've tried it, unfortunately it still isn't responsive.

I should add that the image is actually inside a tab within a webpage.

I'll edit the main question to reflect this.